# Netty: Connecting two channels

Tags: netty

Assume a simple netty server:

When the first client connects, we will remember the channel. If the second client connects, we want to connect it with the first channel, such that everything written on the first channel will be written on the second and vise versa.

Finaly this simple application will be something like a telnet-to-telnet chat.

Answer (score 1):

Add both Channels to a DefaultChannelGroup and store a reference of it. Then when you want to write to the Channels just call the write(...) method on the ChannelGroup.

Comment: Isn't the message written on the ChannelGroup send to all clients in the Group, even to the caller?

Comment: Yes, it will send the message to both side.

Answer (score 0):

As I know, there is no strait forward way to connect two socket channels. (but there are ways to connect non socket channels , two local channels using LocalChannel, arbitrary input output stream using [IOStreamChannel](https://github.com/netty/netty/pull/22)).

I think this problem can be solved by having a bridge channel handler (extends SimpleChannelHandler) in the pipeline, which add/remove channel to a hash table on channelConnected(), channelDisconnected(), and also on messageReceived() get the correct peer channel and write the message to it.